# How to show a component on click in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a header component with its lists and a button which is the Login button.
The header and login component is outside `<Switch>`.

What I am trying to do is when I click the login button in the header component, I want the whole login component to show up as a popup.

How would I achieve that? I know that you can use state but if it is in the same component but I want to show another component. Do I need redux or just use props?

Comment: do you use Redux ?

Comment: No i am not using

Comment: Is **login component** is child of **header component** ?

Comment: No they are just seperate components

Comment: If separate components then i think you need to add Redux

Comment: There is no need for redux in such a simple case. Hoist state to upper component (like `App`) or global context would be enough.

Comment: I take it you're using react router, do you? What version?

Comment: 5.1.2 th version

Answer (score 1):

You can move `isShown` state for your login popup to upper component (or global context) to be able to access it from different places:

```js
// context example
// App.js
const LoginContext = React.createContext(false);

const LoginContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [ isShown, setShown ] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider value={{ isShown, setShown }}>
      {{children}}
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
}

const useLoginPopup = () => React.useContext(LoginContext);

const App = () => (
  <LoginContextProvider>
    // ...
  </LoginContextProvider>
);

// Header component
const Header = () => {
  const { setShown } = useLoginPopup();

  return (
    <Button onClick={ () => setShown(true); }>Login</Button>
  );
};

// Login popup
const Popup = () => {
  const { isShown } = useLoginPopup();

  return isShown && ( ... );
}
```

Comment: So you are saying that I have to write the header and login component inside app.js

Comment: A note to OP, this is using React Hooks which has a different syntax and implementation than 'traditional' React state and lifecycle management.

Comment: Using `useContext` really doesn't seem necessary to me, if anything it just makes things more complicated.

Comment: As i mentioned, you can just hold this state in parent component and pass it to both as a prop. Context just requires less moves.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass a function which changes the state in Parent.

Let's call the components `Parent` and `Child`.

In the Parent component:

```
<Child toggleLoginDialog={this.toggleLoginDialog} />
```

...

```
toggleLoginDialog = () => {
  this.setState({ showDialog: !this.state.showDialog });
}
```

Comment: How do I make my components parent and child?

Comment: These are example names, but simply rendering component 2 inside component 1's JSX would make component 1 the parent and 2 the child.